# validate date should be last date of month in javascript

Tags: javascript

My requirement is to create a month which contains two date fields from date and to date

from date should be starting date of month and end date should be ending date of month..if from date is not starting date it should show message please select starting date of month same for to date also

i tried with this code

```
function getDaysInMonth(aDate){

var m = new Number(aDate.getMonth());
var y = new Number(aDate.getYear());

var tmpDate = new Date(y, m, 28);
var checkMonth = tmpDate.getMonth();
var lastDay = 27;

while(lastDay <= 31){
    temp = tmpDate.setDate(lastDay + 1);
    if(checkMonth != tmpDate.getMonth())
        break;
    lastDay++
}
return lastDay;
```

}

its not working pls help me

Comment: What do you mean when you say, `its not working` ! please set up an example on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Haven't seen `new Number` in a while...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function daysInMonth(iMonth, iYear)
{
    return new Date(iYear, iMonth, 0).getDate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just use the new Date() function in javascript?

new Date(year, month, day)
months go from 0-11
using a day of 0 will result in the previous months last day.

```
//january 1st, 2012 
var d = new Date(2012, 0, 1);
alert(d)

//last day of january 2012 (month 1, day 0)
var d2 = new Date(2012, 1,0);
alert(d2);
```

Comment: i am getting the dates using date control...my req is to when i select another date instaed of first date in a month it should show alert box...please select first date